# Rename File according to file path and Save as a CSV File

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to rename the file to the fifth file number then add on import-TMP-AD-IFI-REV12

The file path only changes for the fifth file for new jobs (the bolded part)
R:\3.0  Projects\2.0  Current Projects\2021 JOBS\ **999111-DO-Customer-Description** \2.0  Estimate\2.7  Final Estimates\999111import-TMP-IFI-REV12.CSV

Such as for this example it will become ***999111import-TMP-IFI-REV12***

The file is to create a copy of the xlsm then saves it as a CSV

```
Sub OverwriteData_In_CSV()

Dim CSVfile
***CSVfile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataFeed").Cells("N1")***
' ^ needs to be rewritten to properly save with new name.
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foundation Budget Template")

'

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ws.Select
ws.Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CSVfile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'
End Sub
```

```
Function getName(pf): getName = Split(Mid(pf, InStrRev(pf, "\") + 1), ".")(0): End Function


Sub Test()

MsgBox getName(ActiveWorkbook.FullName)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I fail to understand what exactly, you are trying to achieve but I can tell you two things.

1. You don't need to `Select` a worksheet in order to copy it to the clipboard. Instead, I would worry about the range from that sheet that is to be copied (though Excel might indeed preempt your omission).
2. The code below is a demonstration of how to manipulate file names. You will find what you need in it. The procedure is self-contained and ready to run. It is also fully annotated for you to easily understand it.

   Sub Snippet()

   ```
   Const Original      As String = "R:\3.0 Projects\2.0 Current Projects\2021 JOBS\999111-DO-Customer-Description\" & _
                                   "2.0 Estimate\2.7 Final Estimates\999111import-TMP-IFI-REV12.CSV"

   Dim Ext             As String           ' file extension
   Dim Fn              As String           ' file name
   Dim Path            As String           ' file path
   Dim Ffn             As String           ' full file name
   Dim Sp()            As String

   ' extract the extension
   Sp = Split(Original, ".")               ' the split is 0-based
   Ext = Sp(UBound(Sp))
   ReDim Preserve Sp(UBound(Sp) - 1)
   Ffn = Join(Sp, ".")
   MsgBox "File & Path = " & Ffn & vbCr & _
          "Extension = " & Ext

   ' extrac the file name
   Sp = Split(Original, "\")
   Fn = Sp(UBound(Sp))
   MsgBox "File name with extension = " & Fn
   Sp = Split(Fn, ".")                     ' the split is 0-based
   MsgBox "File name without extension = " & Sp(0) & vbCr & _
          "Exension = " & Sp(1)

   ' extract a folder from the full file name
   Sp = Split(Original, "\")
   MsgBox "5th path element = " & Sp(4)    ' 5th element = #4

   ' replace or modify the 5th element
   Sp = Split(Original, "\")
   Fn = Sp(UBound(Sp))
   Sp(4) = Split(Fn, ".")(0)
   Ffn = Join(Sp, "\")
   MsgBox "Original Ffn: " & Original & vbCr & vbCr & _
          "Changed 5th element: " & Ffn

   ' extract the path from a full file name
   Sp = Split(Original, "\")
   ReDim Preserve Sp(UBound(Sp) - 1)
   Path = Join(Sp, "\")
   MsgBox "Observe: path does NOT end on back-slash:" & vbCr & Path

   ' append a file name to path
   Sp = Split(Path, "\")
   Fn = "My File Name" & "." & Ext
   ReDim Preserve Sp(UBound(Sp) + 1)
   Sp(UBound(Sp)) = Fn
   Ffn = Join(Sp, "\")
   MsgBox "Full File Name = " & Ffn
   ```

   End Sub